# Apollo Graphql: Replaying query

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I got a use case where I need to replay a query, this needs to be done for repopulating all caches when there is an updated data.

or

Is there a way to call a query from inside the apollo graphql server?

Comment: client asks, it isn't pushed ... can poll, subscribe, refresh after mutation ... what use case, exactly/by example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the incoming request - headers, body etc. in a variable and then when all the functions have finished executing, fire that same request using some axios/fetch to your own server.